# Shopify Cache - what actions lead to clearing the cache

Tags: caching, shopify

I can't find enough infos about shopifys cache system.

I know if the template is modified the cache gets cleared and the next call will build a new cache. But I wonder, if the code in just 1 `section` or `snipped` changed, will this empty the whole cache, or just the cache for this section`or`snipped`?

And more important, what happens if we update product infos or the stockquantity? will this also empty the cache? (Updates run over a Shopify App that probably use the Shopify API to update the stockquantity)

The reason for my question is that on that shop the TTFB (Time to first byte) is high if the shop is uncached. And a lot of time the shop is indeed uncached without any manual modification on the template. Now I try to find the reason why this shop is uncached so often.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify cache system, Under normal circumstances a cache refresh should happen only occasionally - when you change a theme setting, add/remove an app, or have a developer publish a new version of your shop.

You can use the developer tools in Google Chrome to measure time to first byte (TTFB). Also debug every page independently like product page, collection and home page.

Please review below blog, very helpful to monitor Slow Liquid code.

https://www.pluginuseful.com/blogs/ecommerce-blog/can-shopify-liquid-code-slow-down-a-shop